# Did I accidentally short something? My Arduino UNO board does not communicate with the computer anymore

Tags: arduino-uno

I had my sketch uplaoded and everything was working fine when I tried connecting one of the input pins(pre-configured as digital INPUT) to 12V, just to see if this was being read as a HIGH as well.
It seems to have done something and the board stopped working. Moreover, all pins seem to be stuck at HIGH!

So far Ive tried the following:

- reset button: doesnt help
- re-upload: doesn't work - it says not in sync

Physically nothing seems to be burnt/blown. What am I missing? Have I fried my board? I hope not. PS: It was connected to a 12V external power source

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have an Uno with the ATMega328 in a socket, you could just replace the chip with a new one (with bootloader pre-programmed). If it's the SMD version, you're out of luck (unless you have a friend that does SMD soldering).

Comment: @Gerben :That seems like a good option, do you know where I can get a bootloader programmed ATMega328?

Comment: @Gerben : Do you know where I can get a bootloader programmed ATMega 328? I think i can replace it, luckily my board came with an IC socket.

Comment: I don't know where you live. But try stores that also sell regular arduino's. E.g. [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10524) sells them.

Comment: @Gerben Thanks Gerben. I found some for a good price on Amazon.   Thank God for Amazon! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the arduino's input pins are not tolerant of 12 volts, You have likely caused permanent damage to the chip =(. There is a regulator that makes it capable of being *powered* by 12 volts, but the input pins are different.

If you look at table 30-1 on the datasheet for the Uno's controller [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) you can see the input characteristics. The arduino is powered at 5v, so the max digital input voltage is 5.5v

Comment: Thats good to know. I assumed they could take anything up to 20V!(as rather silly assumption. Looks like I will have to use a voltage divider to sample the input voltage and get it under 5V for my use. Thanks Brett!